# error using jquery.each on data returned by promise.done

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am new with Promises.
This is also my first post on stackoverflow. 
I am trying to refactor the following procedure using promises:

```
var listBuilder = (function() {

$.post("sc.php",{task: "getLocations"},function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i,item) {
        $('<li>',{id: "loc-" + item.idlocatii, text: item.denumire})
            .appendTo("#lista")
            .addClass("locationList")
            .draggable({
                revert: "invalid",
                helper: "clone"
            });
    });
},'json');

})();
```

So I came with the following code to replace the above:

```
var listBuilder = (function() {

function addListItem(item) {
    $('<li>',{id: "loc-" + item.idlocatii, text: item.denumire})
        .appendTo("#lista")
        .addClass("locationList")
        .draggable({
            revert: "invalid",
            helper: "clone"
        });
}

var getLocations = $.post("sc.php",{task: "getLocations"},'json');

getLocations.done(function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i,item) {
        addListItem(item);
    });
});

})();
```

The refactored version of code returns the error below:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1026' in
>   [{"idlocatii":"1","denumire":"Hirsch
>   Hopfen"},{"idlocatii":"2","denumire":"Berlinerstr.
>   24"},{"idlocatii":"3","denumire":"Pfalzerstr.
>   26"},{"idlocatii":"4","denumire":"Christophal......}]

Can you explain where is the error?

Thank you!

Comment: What gives you: `console.log(typeof data);` ???

Comment: It gives "string"; From php I send an array encoded with json_encode()

Comment: So you need to parse data to an object, see answer below but why you server doesn't return an object is still mysterious then...

Comment: The first version of code works with the same response from the server. And you can see in the error message the structure of the data returned. It's an array of objects.

Comment: I'm agree but as `console.log(typeof data);` returns `string`, that means your server doesn't return an object, for some reason. Or maybe that's the done() method, but i'm not aware of such behaviour

Comment: It could be the done method. The same data returned by $.post worked. It's good to remember that behavior. Thank you very much A. Wolff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the data you're getting back is actually a JSON string and not an object. What happens if you change your getLocations.done block to the following:

```
getLocations.done(function(data) {
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(parsedData, function(i,item) {
        addListItem(item);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hm. Ok, can you try `console.log(typeof parsedData);` immediately before your `$.each` just so we can confirm that we are sending an object to `$.each`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. This code works. Thank you all very much for your help!

Comment: Oh good! I'm so glad to hear that because I was about to be completely stumped! :)